# Authenticating OAuth2.0 with R using httr

Tags: r, api, oauth-2.0, httr

I'm trying to create authenticate into the Letterboxd API using R and the httr package. The [Letterboxd docs](https://api-docs.letterboxd.com/#auth) give instructions, but I am not sure how to put everything together into a URL.

I know the url is:

```
url <- "https://api.letterboxd.com/api/v0/auth/token"
```

And then they want my username and password, presumably as JSON, but what I'll write as a named list since I'm doing this in R:

```
login_info <- list(
  grant_type = "password",
  username = "myemail@gmail.com",
  password = "extremelysecurepassword"
)
```

I've tried various calls, using `GET()`, `oauth2.0_token()`, `oauth_endpoint()` functions from the httr package.

I feel like I have all the necessary information and am circling around a solution, but I can't quite nail it.

The docs contain this information:

> When generating or refreshing an access token, make a form request to the /auth/token endpoint with Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded and Accept: application/json headers

(Full text is linked to above)

And I'm not sure how to add that information; in working with APIs through R, I'm used to just sending URLs with UTM parameters, but the inputs they want don't work here using `?` and `&`.

I'm aware of [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43583351/how-do-i-request-an-api-token-with-httr), but it looks like it relies on having a secret token already. And I don't seem to be able to generate a secret token inside of the GUI of Letterboxd.com, which is again what I'm used to doing with authentication. I think I need to feed it those sources of information above in `login_info` to the `url`, but I don't quite know how to connect the dots.

How do I authenticate to the Letterboxd API using R?

Answer (score 1):

This runs for me but I get a 401 Unauthorized since you correctly did not supply valid credentials.  It looks like there is a python library for this API https://github.com/swizzlevixen/letterboxd  if you need hints how to make subsequent requests.

sign_request() is mimicking python library's [api.py#L295-L304](https://github.com/swizzlevixen/letterboxd/blob/4a39ad57ce9dd31f95626f6a943378aaae9cde30/letterboxd/api.py#L295-L304)

```
sign_request <- function(apisecret, url, method, body = "") {

  signing_bytes <- as.raw(c(charToRaw(method), 0, charToRaw(url), 0, charToRaw(body)))

  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/31209556/8996878
  # https://stackoverflow.com/q/54606193/8996878

  digest::hmac(key = apisecret, object = signing_bytes, algo = "sha256", serialize = FALSE)
}

url <- "https://api.letterboxd.com/api/v0/auth/token"

login_info <- list(
  grant_type = "password",
  username = "myemail@gmail.com",
  password = "extremelysecurepassword"
)

apikey <- "mytopsecretapikey"
apisecret <- "YOUR_API_SECRET"
method <- "POST"

params <- list(
  apikey = apikey,
  nonce = uuid::UUIDgenerate(),
  timestamp = round(as.numeric(Sys.time()))
)

# now we need to sign the request
body <- paste(names(login_info), login_info, sep = "=", collapse = "&")
body <- URLencode(body)
body <- gsub("@","%40", body) # something URLencode doesn't do but post does

destination <- httr::parse_url(url)
destination$query <- params
post_url_with_params <- httr::build_url(destination)

signature <- sign_request(apikey, post_url_with_params, method, body)

token_request <- httr::POST(url, httr::add_headers(
  "Accept" = "application/json",
  "Authorization" = paste0("Signature ", signature)
),
query = params,
body = login_info, encode = "form", httr::verbose()
)

token_body <- httr::content(token_request, type = "application/json")

# look for the value of"access_token"
```

Comment: Thanks! Using my credentials (tried both username and email), I still get: ```> token_request
Response [https://api.letterboxd.com/api/v0/auth/token]
  Date: 2022-09-23 01:53
  Status: 401
  Content-Type: application/json
  Size: 60 B```

Comment: while ```> token_body
$message
[1] "clientId or signature missing"

$type
[1] "request"```

Comment: Looks like there are url parameters too, the python library posted to https://api.letterboxd.com/api/v0/auth/token?apikey=%22YOUR_KEY_HERE%22&nonce=fe7f6d84-acf1-4ad8-9c0f-ed06e87dacf6&timestamp=1663907393

Comment: I requested api credentials so I can see if I can get it to work

Comment: Still haven't received my creds so I can't successfully run the edited code.  It should be closer to what the python library does at least.

Comment: where do you get the apikey and apisecret? I had the understanding that part of authenticating was providing the password to get those. I can't find a place to generate them on their website (like one can with Twitter, e.g.)

Comment: Ah, I thought you already had them.  https://letterboxd.com/api-beta/ says the api is private and to email them to get "early" api access (early in that the python library is 4 years old).  Their [ruby client's readme](https://github.com/grantyb/letterboxd-api-example-ruby-client) says<br/> >  "Although the Letterboxd API isn’t public yet (as at 2017-06-12), we have seeded some developers with API keys. If you’re one of the beta testers, please fill in your API_KEY and API_SECRET that were provided to you in examples.rb".

Comment: ah bummer, idk why this information wasn't on api-docs.letterboxd.com. I'll email